# Dual screen with JUST extended desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Im using a dual monitor set-up a lot, but i have a problem. I need to forbid to clone the dektop, i want to use just the extended desktop feature. Can it be done somehow?
It's a problem because, when is start my system with two monitor it starts automaticaly with cloned desktop. When i use the hotkey to switch beatween monitors the same problem occours. Always going to the screen resolution options is pain in the ***.

I have a intel hd3000 videocard (sandy bridge)

Thanx a lot

Comment: Allright, thx, but often i need to switch beatween single and extended diplay. The xorg way can solve this feature?

Comment: What configuration utility? (for me text editor isnt an utility :) )

Comment: system settings -> displays -> detect (once it's connected)

Comment: Allright, after upgrading video driver from the x-swat ppa, the defualt display utility what you mentioned before working fine. Thx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use hotkeys, set it in xorg.conf or a configuration utility.

Try: system settings -> displays -> detect (once it's connected)

Then you can switch your screen orientation and enable displays.